# Does an ideal of a ring/semiring necessarily contain identity?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, semiring

A subset $I$ of a ring/semiring $R$ is said to be an ideal of $R$ if $x+y\in I$ for all $x,y\in I$ and $x.a\in I$($a.x\in I$) for all $a\in R$. Since $0\in R,$ $x.0\in I$ for all $x\in I$ or $0\in I.$ This shows that the identity $0$ necessarily belongs to $I$. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Moreover, $(I,+)$ must form a subgroup of $(R,+)$  for a ring $R$ so that we know we must have $0 \in I$.

Answer (score 2):

That's not just intuition.  It's an actual proof that any ideal must contain the additive identity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  $0$ has to be in the ideal, since, as you said, $0\in\mathcal R$.  So $0=0\cdot x\in\mathscr I$, for any $x\in\mathscr I$.